# cant clear cache from my browser in php

Tags: caching, clear-cache

```
<?php
$_SESSION['test']="demo";
echo $_SESSION['test'];
function clearBrowserCache() {
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
}
clearBrowserCache();
?>
```

i want to make one php file which can clear cache browser. is that something wrong in my code please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not echo anything before sending headers.

```
<?php
function clearBrowserCache() {
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");
}
clearBrowserCache();

$_SESSION['test']="demo";
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

Otherwise, enable `output_buffering` in the `php.ini`

Comment: thank you for your reply can you please tell me how to remove cache still it is not removing cache from browser .

Comment: browser cache .

Comment: You can't clear the browser cache from the server. That could be a serious vulnerability. This previous code allows you to only tell the browser not to cache your current "page".