# add one function which can clear all browser cache using php code

Tags: php, function, browser, browser-cache

```
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
  <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>


  <?php
  function clearBrowserCache() {
  header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
  header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
  header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  
  header ("Pragma: no-cache");
  }
  clearBrowserCache();

  $_SESSION['test']="demo";
  //echo $_SESSION['test'];
 clearstatcache() ;
 ?>
```

- this code is only  allowing browser to not to catch cache .but i want to delete all  cache using simple code is there any way to do it ? simply i when i run this code my browser's cache should get deleted. how to do it ?

Comment: however you can't clear client browser cache

Comment: @JYoThI so there is no way ? we can clear catch using some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cant clear cache from my browser in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261575/cant-clear-cache-from-my-browser-in-php)

Comment: You had asked this same question yesterday too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261575/cant-clear-cache-from-my-browser-in-php AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262143/cache-clear-is-not-working-in-php). You need to close/delete them and keep only one open. DO NOT ASK same question again and again. Kindly delete/close them.

Comment: @Milan chhedadidnt get the proper answer  for this question sure i will delete it

Comment: If you didn't get the answer, you can rephrase or add bounty but don't create add same question again. Thanks.

Comment: @Milan chheda sure next time i will keep this in my mind :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear browser cache with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php)